# Bode is plot despite of high quality factor

Tags: sallen-key

I'm trying to simulate the following circuit in LTSpice:
[image]

As can be seen, the Gain
$$ G = 1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_4} = 1 + 1.6 = 2.6 \Rightarrow Q = 2.5$$

Which should give a peak, but I'm getting following plot:
[image]

I've tried changing the value of capacitance and found that if it is higher than 30-40pF, there is a peak.
How this behaviour can be explained?

I've checked [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112521/resonant-frequency-from-bode-plot) question but as per the answer I should get a peak, since the damping ratio is lower than 0.707.

Comment: Capacitors of 1pF do not work in reality and do not work for real opamp models which have input capacitors larger than 1pf. Try to use an IDEAL opamp model - and you will see the peak (if the damping is below 0.707).

Comment: Why did you simulate an Opamp that has a specifically low Gain-Bandwidth product of 0.7 MHz up to 5 GHz? That doesn't make much sense! (in fact, it makes no sense at all, imagine what that thing does at 5 GHz: not much at all.)

Comment: Unless your intention is to see an opamp's limitations, use a VCVS (E source) with `1e5` or so gain.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @LvW No idea, I've got this as an experiment. Can you suggest any other platform which might give me a more reliable result?

Comment: @XRFXLP Press `F2` and select `e`, or `e2`, and use that instead of an opamp. Make the gain `1e5` or so.

Comment: VCVE = Voltage-Controlled Voltage Source (pretty googleable term together with the word "SPICE")

Comment: "I've got this as an experiment."  Meaning your prof told you to use that op-amp, and investigate behavior with C = \$1\mathrm{pF}\$?  Either they haven't done enough work in industry, or they want you to see what happens when theory fights practice, and loses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm setting aside the fact that a \$1\mathrm{pF}\$ cap just isn't realizable in practice on a circuit board.  The input capacitance to the op-amp is probably greater than that.  There's a *reason* it's hard to find capacitors with values less than \$4.7\mathrm{pF}\$ or so.

You are doing your calculations assuming an ideal op-amp.  However, the expected peak for your filter is going to be in the neighborhood of \$16\mathrm{MHz}\$ (give or take a factor of \$\sqrt{2}\$ or \$\sqrt{3}\$).  At the same time, the gain bandwidth product of your op-amp is only \$700\mathrm{kHz}\$.

Basically, not only is your op-amp not ideal at the design frequency, it's not even really an op-amp.

You could use an op-amp that has a gain of at least 100 at your design frequency -- but using \$10\mathrm{k}\Omega\$ resistors and \$1\mathrm{pF}\$ caps in a circuit that needs to be good up to a \$\mathrm{GHz}\$ is just not going to work.